# VBA Copying from one Word Doc to Another from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have an Excel Worksheet that opens a blank Word document as the "Master" and a "Temporary" separate Word Document.  I'm trying to move to the end of "Master", Copy the entirety of "Temporary" and paste to "Master" and then enter a page break on "Master".  I'm getting errors on ".Selection.EndKey unit:=wdStory Extend:=wdMove" , ".Add.Content.Paste" and ".Selection.InsertBreak Type:=7" and I'm not sure why.  I'll be iterating multiple "Temporary" documents and adding them to "Master" one by one but don't want to move to the loops until I can do one basic round of copy-paste from "Temporary" to "Master".  There's alos a boomark replace subroutine that I'm not showing to reduce complexity from the community, hence the "Fields.Update" on the "Temporary" doc.

```
Public wb As Excel.Workbook
Public Path As String
Public MasterWordObj
Public MasterCOI
Public TempWordObj
Public TempCOI

Sub COI()

'Initialize Worksheet/Workbook and unprotect worksheet and cells
  ActiveSheet.Unprotect
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("COI").Cells.Locked = False
  Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
  
  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'Path for Master COI Template
    Path = "xxx"

'Create a Master Word Session
  Set MasterWordObj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  Set MasterCOI = MasterWordObj.Documents.Add


'Define Path for Temporary COI Template
    Path = "XXX"

'Create a Temp Word Session
  Set TempWordObj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  Set TempCOI = TempWordObj.Documents.Add(Path)

'Activate Temporary Word Template, Update Fields, Copy All
    With TempWordObj
            .Visible = True
            .Selection.WholeStory
            .Selection.Fields.Update
            .Selection.WholeStory
            .ActiveWindow.WindowState = 1
            .Activate
            .Selection.WholeStory
            .Selection.Copy
    End With
           
'Paste and insert Page Break in Master Template
    With MasterWordObj
        .Visible = True
        .ActiveWindow.WindowState = 1
        .Selection.EndKey unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdMove
        .Add.Content.Paste
        .Selection.InsertBreak Type:=7
        .Activate
    End With
  
 'Release the Word objects to save memory and exit macro
ErrorExit:
   Set MasterWordObj = Nothing
   Set TempWordObj = Nothing
   Exit Sub

'Error Handling routine
ErrorHandler:
   If Err Then
      MsgBox "Error No: " & Err.Number & "; There is a problem"
      
      If Not MasterWordObj Is Nothing Then
        MasterWordObj.Quit False
      End If
      
      If Not TempWordObj Is Nothing Then
        TempWordObj.Quit False
      End If
    
      Resume ErrorExit
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If you haven't added a reference to Word in your Excel VBA project then constants like `wdStory` etc will not be available to your Excel VBA.  This is flagged up if you use `Option Explicit` in your modules (and you absolutely should do that).  You either need to add the reference, or declare the missing constants and their values in your VBA.

Comment: Hi Tim.  I'm using the reference to the Word Object "With MasterWordObj"

Comment: The With block only scopes the contained code to your object variable.  You need to add a reference to the Word object library. See - https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/add-object-library-reference-vba/

Comment: I added the "Word" Reference Library.  I already had the Excel Reference Library selected.  It's working now!  Thanks Tim.  Do you want to put an answer in there so that I can upvote you for the credit?

Comment: You haven't typed any of your variables. As a result they are all of the default type which is `Variant`. You should always declare your variables like this: `Dim Name As Type`

Comment: You do not need to - and should not - employ separate Word application objects for the different documents. For comprehensive code to combine multiple Word documents, see: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/43339-combine-multiple-word-documents.html. If the documents all have the same page layout, you can omit the LayoutTransfer sub and the call to it. To run this from Excel, you'd need to either use early binding, or late binding with the Word constants declared or replace by their numeric values.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't added a reference to Word in your Excel VBA project then constants like wdStory etc will not be available to your Excel VBA. This is flagged up if you use Option Explicit in your modules (and you absolutely should do that).

You either need to add the reference, or declare the missing constants and their values in your VBA.